# Setting Dynamodb data design using Graphql

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I'm new to the AWS world and I'm trying to build a React Native app (using expo) with AWS Amplify on the back end.
For the Dynamodb tables design I would want to do something like this:
(just an example for an "Ad" item)
Partition Key: AD#<ad_id>
Sort Key: BUSINESS#<business_id>
Attributes: ..... (this part doesn't matter in this example)

How can I setup the Dynamodb using the Graphql to create this type of keys, not just those simple ones with Partition key: ID and Sort Key USER_ID?

In every tutorial that I've watched is based on the "just the id" type of keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure on the question that you're asking, but you can choose any value as your partition key as long as it's a string/number/binary.

Without knowing anything about your use-case I would suggest this type of schema, where you can do queries such as give me all the ads for a particular business, but thats an assumption.

| PK | SK | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BUSINESS#<business_id> | AD#<ad_id> | some data |

As for the graphQL aspect, i suggest you read this page of documentation which goes over the key aspects:

https://aws.amazon.com/graphql/graphql-dynamodb-data-modeling/